# How to reinstall Unity in 16.10?

Tags: unity, 16.10

I recently tried out Pantheon DE and after I purged it from my system, I am seeing a whole host of problems with the DE - improperly sized panels, misfitting windows title etc. The only option is left to reinstall Unity as Pantheon messed by GTK. How do that???

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal or `Alt + F2`

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

If it doesn't work with the problem of dependency

`sudo apt install -f ubuntu-desktop`